# How do I select only rows with at least 2 non-missing values

Tags: sql

How do I write a query so that I get the numbers of rows where there are at least 2 non null values in the columns for each ID? In the example below, there would be 2 rows with 2 or more non null values.

[image]

I'm getting an error Incorrect syntax near '>' with the below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM db1
WHERE (var1 IS NOT NULL) + (var2 IS NOT NULL) + (var3 IS NOT NULL) + (var4 IS NOT NULL) >= 2 ;
```

Comment: how are you expecting to add boolean results and then checking those booleans to be bigger than 2? What is a boolean plus a boolean? Also tag your RDMS (sql server, ms access, oracle, something else?)

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work for MySql, so I guess it's not the database that yo use.
Using standard SQL you can do it with CASE expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM db1
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN (var1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN (var2 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN (var3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN (var4 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 2 ;
```